# I've updated my Google email address, now when I log in to stack overflow, I'm a new user?

Tags: discussion, login

So I changed my Google email address, and now when I log in with Google, I'm a new user - how do I get my old account back ?

Comment: See the [help] http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: found the merging stuff, thanks