# Primary email on Google changed, now I can't log into Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, authentication

I used to have a Google login, xxxx@live.com, which I used to log into Stack Overflow with.

Recently, I bought a tablet and had to create a [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) account. This then replaced my primary email for my Google account to my Gmail address. Ever since then, Stack Overflow is not able to recognise me when I try to log in. It keeps picking up my *@gmail.com* address instead of my *@live.com* address.

How on earth can I fix this?

My *@live.com* username on Stack Overflow is Dusty Roberts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've updated my Google email address, now when I log in to stack overflow, I'm a new user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196890/ive-updated-my-google-email-address-now-when-i-log-in-to-stack-overflow-im-a)

Comment: this is not a duplicate, and i cannot merge my accounts, because i am unable to log into my previous account

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery, then set up the account to use your new OpenID.

Otherwise, see http://www.stackoverflow.com/contact and explain the problem.